# How to add today's date into BigQuery destination table name

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am new to Google Cloud BigQuery. I am trying to schedule a job which runs a query periodically. In each run, I would like to create a destination table whose name contains today's date. I need something like:

bq query --destination=[project]:[dataset].[table name_date]

Is it possible to do that automatically? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Important on SO - you can mark accepted answer by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. See meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/… for why it is important! Also important to vote on answer. Vote up answers that are helpful. ... You can check about what to do when someone answers your question - stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Following these simple rules you increase your own reputation score and at the same time you keep us motivated to answer your questions :o) please consider!

Answer (score 2):

This example is using shell scripting.

```
YEAR=$(date -d "$d" '+%Y')
MONTH=$(date -d "$d" '+%m')
DAY=$(date -d "$d" '+%d')

day_partition=$YEAR$MONTH$DAY

bq_partitioned_table="${bq_table}"'_'"${day_partition}"

bq query --destination=$bq_partitioned_table
```

See if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you put your periodic query? 
I always put in datalab notebook, and then use module datetime to get today's date and assign to the destination table name. 
then set the notebook to run every day at certain time. Works great.